# Css and jQuery: How do I trigger the repositioning of a CSS3-animated element back to where it was before the animation?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

http://jsfiddle.net/cD4Gr/4/

Le Code:

```
$j(document).bind('click', function() { 
    $j("#test").css({ bottom:0px })
    });
```

Looking in the inspector, even when the element is at the top of the page, it still says it's bottom value is 0.

Maybe I need to play the animation in reverse somehow? or play a different animation? (Using Bottom %, rather than top %)

Comment: Your fiddle didn't work for me, but there is an event that is fired you can bind to when an animation ends.

Comment: Regarding your % vs px question, I'm pretty sure that if your value is 0, you don't have to specify units. Maybe that's only true in straight CSS.

Comment: @Chovy, I'm using webkit animations. Make sure you try a webkit browser.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot, tried that. No change. =\

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean about the animation. Your example has no animation. The div just appears at the bottom of the page as I would expect from your code.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot, I'm using webkit CSS animations. For testing purposes I don't bother using CSS properties for all browsers until I get the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were thinking you can make a second keyframe block to reset it back to the bottom:

```
@-webkit-keyframes reset_to_bottom {
    0%, 100% {
        top: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1000000;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

then have your jQuery change the animation name:

```
$j("#test").css({
    '-webkit-animation-name': 'reset_to_bottom'
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cD4Gr/5/)

When using `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` forwards will maintain the last keyframe styles, so `top:0%` is still set which is why `bottom:0` was having no effect

---

for fun...switch between animation's each click

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cD4Gr/6/)

```
$j(document).bind('click', function() {
    if ($j("#test").css('-webkit-animation-name') == "slide_to_top") {
        $j("#test").css({'-webkit-animation-name': 'reset_to_bottom'});
    } else {
        $j("#test").css({'-webkit-animation-name': 'slide_to_top'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the situation correctly, I think these modifications should fix your problem:

CSS:

```
#test {
  ...
  //bottom: 0px; //Remove this line
  top:100%;      //Replace with this
  ...
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//$j("#test").css({ bottom:0px })
$j("#test").css({ top:0 })
```

On a side note, I prefer using the jQuery `animate()` function rather than CSS for animations, mainly because it already has support for all major browsers. That way, I don't have to worry about including multiple CSS styles for different browsers.