# run keyframes-animation on click more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit-animation

i have a div that it have image content .i wanna implement animation when i click in image but  it do only with first click and next click in image is Ineffective.what is problem and how can i solve it?

```
$(function () {
         $('div.c').bind('mousedown', function () {
             var $elem = $(this);
             $elem.stop(true)
             .css({ "-webkit-animation-name": "xi",
             "-webkit-animation-duration": "3s",
             "-webkit-animation-timing-function": "ease", 
             "-webkit-animation-delay": "1s",            
              })
              })})
```

and

```
     @-webkit-keyframes xi{ 0% {
  left: 100px;
}

40% {
  left: 150px;
}

60% {
  left: 75px;
}

100% {
  left: 100px;
}}
```

Comment: i think when keyframe reach to 100 percent do not reset with next click because when i refresh the page i can implement animation again.

Comment: I'd suggest adding that to the op ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset your animation with a second keyframe block as suggested here:
[Css and jQuery: How do I trigger the repositioning of a CSS3-animated element back to where it was before the animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932672/css-and-jquery-how-do-i-trigger-the-repositioning-of-a-css3-animated-element-ba)

Here's also a possible solution on how to reset your animation when it's completed:
[Is there a callback on completion of a CSS3 animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186454/is-there-a-callback-on-completion-of-a-css3-animation)