# Firefox not retriggering CSS animation on 're-added' element

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, animation

I'm working on a slideshow where the captions are using animate.css to transition in from the left. The simplest way I've found to get this working is to .hide() all captions and then .show() with jQuery on the slide change.

In every browser the css animation is retriggered once an animating element is 're-added' to the page except for Firefox. Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LEWUk/1/

```
// See fiddle

$('#reset').click(function(){

    $('.animated').hide(0).show(0);
});
```

Comment: That's a complicated one.. have you taken a look at this thread yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279646/run-keyframes-animation-on-click-more-than-once

Answer (score 0):

Getting Error on console

> [08:06:13.645] Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use
>   getAttribute() instead. @
>   http://jsfiddle.net/js/moo-clientcide-1.3.js?jobofferinsidebar:3714

See the [`Bug`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12072)

1. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661327
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690120
3. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10735

You can try this [run keyframes-animation on click more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279646/run-keyframes-animation-on-click-more-than-once)

Comment: The warning (not error) about `getAttributeNode` does not seem to have anything to do with what is asked. You'll get this warning each time you open a (blank) jsfiddle, but being just a warning, everything still works for the time being.