# Why does keyframes animation on click only trigger once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

Below is my code, the keyframes animation only happens on first click. Any ideas?

***Solved, see my answer below***

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".audioplayer-playpause").click(function(){
  $('.audioplayer-playpause').css({

    //for firefox
    "-moz-animation-name":"playPausePulse",
    "-moz-animation-duration":"0.1s",
    "-moz-animation-iteration-count":"1",
    "-moz-animation-fill-mode":"forwards",

    //for safari & chrome
    "-webkit-animation-name":"playPausePulse",
    "-webkit-animation-duration":"0.1s",
    "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"1",
    "-webkit-animation-fill-mode":"forwards",

  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
@-moz-keyframes playPausePulse /*--for webkit--*/{
    0%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
    50%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
    100%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes playPausePulse /*--for webkit--*/{
    0%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
    50%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
    100%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
}
```

This is very relevant but I visited both reference links and couldn't find a solution that worked:
[run keyframes-animation on click more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279646/run-keyframes-animation-on-click-more-than-once)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Thomas.

Comment: Mark your own answer as the correct one if it is solved, there is no need to mention it in title

Comment: I can't do that for two days

Comment: I have +1 your answer for now so people see it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

I added a listener to give the element a new / resetting animation at the end

**JQUERY**

```
$(".audioplayer-playpause").click(function(){
  $('.audioplayer-playpause').css({

  //for firefox
  "-moz-animation-name":"playPausePulse",
  "-moz-animation-duration":"0.1s",
  "-moz-animation-iteration-count":"1",
  "-moz-animation-fill-mode":"forwards",

  //for safari & chrome
  "-webkit-animation-name":"playPausePulse",
  "-webkit-animation-duration":"0.1s",
  "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"1",
  "-webkit-animation-fill-mode":"forwards",

  });
});

   $(".audioplayer-playpause").bind('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
        $(".audioplayer-playpause").css({
            '-moz-animation-name': 'playPausePulseReset',
            '-webkit-animation-name': 'playPausePulseReset',
        });
   });
```

**CSS**

```
@-moz-keyframes playPausePulse /*--for webkit--*/{
  0%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
  50%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
  100%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes playPausePulse /*--for webkit--*/{
  0%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
  50%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
  100%   {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);}
}

@-moz-keyframes playPausePulseReset /*--for webkit--*/{
  0%, 100% {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playPausePulseReset /*--for webkit--*/{
  0%, 100% {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use .on() or .live() like this

```
$(".audioplayer-playpause").on('click',function(){});
```

or like this

```
 $(document).on('click',".audioplayer-playpause",function(){});
```

so your code will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".audioplayer-playpause").on('click',function(){
       $(this).css({

       //for firefox
       "-moz-animation-name":"playPausePulse",
       "-moz-animation-duration":"0.1s",
       "-moz-animation-iteration-count":"1",
       "-moz-animation-fill-mode":"forwards",

       //for safari & chrome
       "-webkit-animation-name":"playPausePulse",
       "-webkit-animation-duration":"0.1s",
       "-webkit-animation-iteration-count":"1",
       "-webkit-animation-fill-mode":"forwards",

       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried it be unfortunately it didn't work. I have since found a solution, will post here shortly.